# 自與 - what is the meaning?

Tags: translation

Here is a passage which comments on Mencius 万章上 chapter:

嘗聞趙相國，又論此云自我竭力耕田至於我何哉，皆恝義。此言亦是。蓋既曰不若是恝，則須見其所以為恝者如何方得。且如註所云，是為其身則能竭力耕田恭為子職而已。責已塞而無復加矣。但不知父母之不見愛，以我有何罪而然云爾，則不可謂非怨父母，恐其失不止於恝而已。夫善則自與，罪則不知，雖非舜之大孝，豈至是哉。

All is more or less clear, besides the last sentence "夫善則自與，罪則不知，雖非舜之大孝，豈至是哉". Particularly, I am not sure what does "自與" mean in this context.

Any help would be appreciated.

The passage above refers to Mencius discussing the story of Shun not knowing why his parents do not love him:

"萬章問曰，舜往於田，號泣於旻天。何為其號泣也。孟子曰，怨慕也。萬章曰，父母愛之，喜而不忘，父母惡之，勞而不怨。然則舜怨乎。曰，長息問於公明高曰，舜往於田，則吾既得聞命矣。號泣於旻天於父母，則吾不知也。公明高曰，是非爾所知也。夫公明高以孝子之心，為不若是恝。我竭力耕田，共為子職而已矣。父母之不我愛，於我何哉。"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is 与 here means “to approve”, 自与 is 倒装句, “与自”, to approve himself. The usage is similar to 吾与点也 (from 论语 先進)

“夫善則自與，罪則不知，雖非舜之大孝，豈至是哉。” could be:
如果好就夸赞自己，有过错却不知道，虽然不是舜那样的大孝子，却怎么能这样呢。